# SQL Server 2012 - Synchronizing tables on different servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I need your assistance.

I have a table that I must synchronize in near real time.

There is however a couple of challenges that I'm sitting with:

1. The table (Table A) to by synchronized do not reside on the same server, but on two different servers. Server A (Production) and Server C (Development).
2. The table (Table A) on server A and server C do not have a primary key, so merge and transactional replication cannot work.
3. Setting triggers up on server A - the production server - is out of the question, this is a operation critical server.
4. Adding a primary key is also out of the question.
5. There is +/- 90 records being added to the table per minute.

Please can anyone assist?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have ruled out so many options for any HA technologies to work..Only solution i could think of  is

1.Write a custom solution in C#,which compares tables and does the necessary merge based on some column like date
2.Write the last written records into some table for the exe to start from there again
3.Trigger this through SQLServer Agent

You can also use [AlwaysOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx) which provides readable secondaries as well,but i am not sure you be failing over production and development ..